# awk to take FS into effect

Tags: awk, gawk, separator

Why does the following happen? How can I understand the logic?

```
$ echo "123456" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="4"; OFS="-"}; {print}'
123456
```

But if I "modify" some of the fields, everything is OK:

```
$ echo "123456" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="4"; OFS="-"}; {$1=$1;print}'
123-56
```

Comment: When you assign anything in awk, awk will reconstruct the record and your changes will take effect. Here `$1=$1` is just a way to do an assignment to force `awk` to reconstruct the record. you can use `$3=$3` or anything you feel "wise" check this for more clarity https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html

Comment: That's what I supposed, but I still can't grasp the logic. Why e.g. when I retrieve $1 (not having assigned anything before), everything is OK?

$ echo "123456" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="4"; OFS="-"}; {print $1}'
123

Comment: Here `$0` is special as compared to `$1` or `$2` , `$0` is made up of these columns and only `$0` get reconstructed unlike other columns.

Comment: Ed Morton, thanks, it is an excellent book, and I read much from it. But when I try to make my own code, there occur such "basic" problems.

Comment: You're welcome and yes it is. In fact the answer you just accepted is a quote from one of the early chapters of that book.

Comment: Yes, I reread the whole chapter today. But frankly speaking I don't fully understand the reason, why it was done this way in awk...

Comment: Yeah often the rationale for a decision like that isn't obvious until you start thinking of what the alternatives might be and then weighing the pros/cons and then you usually end up deciding they got it right (except for FS meaning Input and OFS meaning Output - IFS and OFS would've been more intuitive and consistent with shell and then we could've had `FS` to set both at the same time as is usually what's desired. Oh well....). What way would you expect it do be done?

Comment: I would expect all $i and $0 to change as soon as FS is modified. Robbins labels such a decision (implemented in some variangs of awk) as wrong.

Comment: I've got the logic. It's to be able to have the original $0!

`echo " a b c" | awk '{print; $1=$1; print}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Output Field Separator only takes effect once record has been touched in some way. From the [GNU AWK manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html#Changing-Fields):

> It is important to remember that `$0` is the full record, exactly as it was read from the input. This includes any leading or trailing whitespace, and the exact whitespace (or other characters) that separates the fields.
>
> It is a common error to try to change the field separators in a record simply by setting FS and OFS, and then expecting a plain `print` or `print $0` to print the modified record.
>
> But this does not work, because nothing was done to change the record itself. Instead, you must force the record to be rebuilt, typically with a statement such as `$1 = $1`